# Classification training data, but regression prediction

Tags: machine-learning, probability-theory, neural-networks, classification, features

Suppose I'm performing machine learning on a simple dataset, and have a bunch of training data of the form:

```
x (feature)   y (label)
-----------------------
1             0
2             1
3             1
4             0
5             1
6             1
...
```

Where the labels are values in two classes, $[0, 1]$.  Clearly, this training data lends one to believe that it will be a classification task.

However, suppose I want to output instead the *probability* that a feature will take the class $1$.  Then, my output is more of a regression task.

Consequently, when I'm designing a simple neural network with just a single input layer and single output layer, how many output units should I have?  Should I have two output units, one for each class, and if so, how do I ensure that each pair of outputs will be a valid probability distribution (i.e. sum to one)?  Or should I have only one output unit, and treat the entire problem as a regression task?

There are probably pros/cons to each approach... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a binary classification task.  In the abstract, there are two ways to handle this:

- Most classifiers can output a predicted class *and* a confidence score (which indicates how confident the classifier is in its prediction).  If you don't need a probability, you can use the confidence score.  If you want to turn it into a probability, you can use various calibration procedures to turn this into a probability in the range [0,1].
- Some classifiers can output a probability directly.  Generative models in particular are good at this.  For instance, logistic regression outputs both a predicted class and a probability for the class.

If you construct a neural network with $k$ outputs, one per class, using a softmax output and train it to minimize the cross-entropy loss function, then you can interpret the output as a probability distribution on the classes (though beware that it might be biased or over-confident).  The softmax ensures the outputs are normalized to be in the range [0,1] and to sum to one.

In your case, you can try both approaches (two outputs with softmax; or a single output with a sigmoidal activation function).  The only way to know which will perform better is to try both, but personally, I'd lean towards using two outputs and softmax.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using two outputs and running them through softmax.  I'll look into the logistic regression as well.